# Graph for derivative function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

Please help. I can't display a graph for the derivative of a function.

```
Ls = 1.27; Is = 1.1; S = 3.6; B = 0.136;
A = 2;
i[t_] := A Sin[2 50 \[Pi] t];
\[Psi][t_] := Ls i[t]/Is (1 + (Abs[i[t]/Is])^S)^(-1/(S + B)) ;
d\[Psi][t_] := D[\[Psi][t], t];
Plot[{\[Psi]'[t]}, {t, 0.001, 0.04}]
Plot[{d\[Psi][t]}, {t, 0.001, 0.04}]
```

tried to use:

```
With[{f = d\[Psi][t]}, Plot[f, {t, 0, 0.04}]]
ReleaseHold@HoldForm[Plot][d\[Psi][t], {t, 0, 0.04}]
```

Thank you for your attention, I will be glad for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

[`Abs`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs.html) is a complex function and you cannot take its derivative, use [`RealAbs`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RealAbs.html)

```
Ls = 1.27; Is = 1.1; S = 3.6; B = 0.136;
A = 2;
i[t_] := A Sin[2 50 π t];
ψ[t_] := Ls i[t]/Is (1 + (RealAbs[i[t]/Is])^S)^(-1/(S + B));
```

For `dψ` use [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) rather than [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html)

```
dψ[t_] = D[ψ[t], t];

Plot[ψ'[t], {t, 0.001, 0.04}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[dψ[t], {t, 0.001, 0.04}]
```

[image]